# Proper typing for interface that includes multiple different class constructors?

Tags: typescript

I am stuck trying to write types for an external JavaScript package that provides one big object, the properties of which are (mostly) a bunch of different class constructors. Something along the lines of

```js
class ThingOne {
  constructor(par1, par2) { // guts expecting par1 to be a ThingTwo and par2 a number... }
  aMethod(par) { // wants a string... } 
  // etc etc
}

class ThingTwo {
  constructor(par1, par2) { // wants a string and a boolean... }
  // etc etc
}

var bigObject = { \\ this is what comes out of the package
   ThingOne: ThingOne,
   ThingTwo: ThingTwo
}
```

(in the existing package) with the intended usage being

```
const myTwo = new bigObject.ThingTwo('foo', true);
const myOne = new bigObject.ThingOne(myTwo, 7); 
// etc.
```

So in the .d.ts file I am hand-coding, I am trying to write an interface with which to type `bigObject`. My first attempt was

```js
export interface BigObjectInterface {
  ThingOne(par1: ThingTwo, par2: number): ThingOne;
  ThingTwo(par1: string, par2: boolean): ThingTwo
}

export class ThingOne {
  constructor(par1: ThingTwo, par2: number);
  aMethod(par: string); // etc.
}

export class ThingTwo {
  constructor(par1: string, par2: boolean);
  // etc.
}
```

but as I was expecting this doesn't work since it types for the usage

```
const myTwo = bigObject.ThingTwo('foo', true);
```

not with the `new` operator as intended. On the other hand, `new` in an interface doesn't take a method name, so I don't see how to use that. Nor can I type the `ThingOne` property in the `BigObjectInterface` as just `ThingOne` (e.g. `ThingOne: ThingOne`), since it is not a `ThingOne` object, it's just an alias of the constructor of `ThingOne` (e.g. `bigObject.ThingOne.aMethod('bar')` is not legal.)

So how can one type the `ThingOne` and `ThingTwo` properties in the `BigObjectInterface`?

Comment: Just out of curiosity (I have no problem with the edits) why was the .d.ts tag inappropriate? This is a problem that came up specifically in the (hand-)writing of a .d.ts file, that I would not expect to come up in a TypeScript-only setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest change to your declaration would be to use [the `typeof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) to get the type of the `ThingOne`/`ThingTwo` constructor *values*, so that you can just use those types directly instead of trying to rewrite types for them:

```
interface BigObjectInterface {
  ThingOne: typeof ThingOne;
  ThingTwo: typeof ThingTwo;
}

const myTwo = new bigObject.ThingTwo('foo', true); // okay
const myOne = new bigObject.ThingOne(myTwo, 1); // okay
```

On the other hand, if you really do want to write the type out, you can give the `ThingOne` and `ThingTwo` properties [construct signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures):

```
interface BigObjectInterface {
  ThingOne: { new(par1: ThingTwo, par2: number): ThingOne };
  ThingTwo: { new(par1: string, par2: boolean): ThingTwo }
}

const myTwo = new bigObject.ThingTwo('foo', true); // okay
const myOne = new bigObject.ThingOne(myTwo, 1); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2&filetype=ts#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABAVRlAKgTzlAewDMUBvYYFFAEykQBswAnVBsGGFLACwEsQA5gHkQqclSqICIGABcmAV0SyCTABQImARgBcXPoKwB3AgBoUmgEx6QCiACMoTAJQBuShLABZKLO4FqDWY9OSZ+AWc9ADcCXmp3KgBfCipaNhYUNg59cOMCMg9JaVClFXVNXRRQ8PMrPXsCAnooMBA3QpQAek6UX0QAOg9kqn5ZJyIkVAAhXmF7ACs6WQBJEDGmCeQCiRzBESg9WTxCEh5w-YSJM8MTQ+PiXYE8y+GaOkYMqRlZFHtZoQWSz0Mzmi2Uq3Wmyg7g8XzkKAgODyKAAvChREZfv9Acp+tcniY1AByIiNInmeQKKDtIrfBE4fao9FQTF-UFLPEGYSiNSIvLmLTtYDJUCQWAILYAYWKlOUAGVZuBZAoWJxyB5RuNJo9GeJPD4-AEgkwQvJwpEUDE4i8NWstVt8ci9VRur1ZIghrbIdqQQCwSs7Rttc6daI9KRmUZjZVHSZasxrOi7I4XHp8YzEpcqLGCOHI9HTWFBPGmImGk0Wm001zka9XmkPqwZVj2cpgdj-RD7dCUplm3yTEyMS2-Ryc8TSQRyShKdTLnCfojGWjh2zR7j0zyB2YUIKYckgA)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! In the typescript setting I think of a class like `ThingOne` as a type and did not realize that you could apply typeof to it (to get the type of the constructor) -- that particular handy usage case isn't mentioned in the handbook link on typeof. But in the end, sorry about my ignorance of this feature.